# How do I round a double in Java? (Android Development)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using the following method to return values from the SQLite Database.

```
public String Totalsponsor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_SPONSOR, KEY_SWIMMERLAPS };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
            + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE  + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_SWIMMERLAPS+" DESC", null);

    String result = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getDouble(0) + "\n";
    }

    return result;

}
```

How would could I round the result before returning it?

I attempted:

`for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + Math.round(c.getDouble(0)) + "\n";
        }`

but it didn't appear to work (perhaps I have not understood the round method?).

Edit: I only appear to get the first result.

Comment: Why doesn't `Math.round` work? What is your output, and what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.##"); // here define you can define how much precision you want.

for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) { 
  result = result + df.format(c.getDouble(0)) + "\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Double d=new Double("512.56789");

System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

---

Will give you the result **512.57** as you may expect such.

---

Use it in your code to suite your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Math.floor(), Math.round(), Math.ceiling(). Javadocs is available here with explanation:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html